# How to get rows where values in any column are more than a value?

Tags: r

my data is like this:

```
> head(df)
   ETDPAT04 ETDPAT06 ETDPAT08 ETDPAT12
1:        2        .        3        3
2:       12       12        .       14
3:        6        5        6        7
4:        1        1        1        1
5:        1        3        3        2
6:        3        3        2        4
...
```

how to return all rows where value is any of those columns is more than 61?

I tried to do this:

```
a=df[apply(df, 1, function(row) {any(row > 61)}),]
```

what I got does not satisfy my above mentioned condition. I got this:

```
    > head(a)
   ETDPAT04 ETDPAT06 ETDPAT08 ETDPAT12
1:        6        5        6        7
2:        6        6        7        8
3:        8        3        6        4

...
```

there is no data in my dataframe in those columns which is more than 61, so I should get zero results.

```
colMax <- function(df) sapply(df, max, na.rm = TRUE)
colMax(df)
ETDPAT04 ETDPAT06 ETDPAT08 ETDPAT12 
     "9"      "9"      "9"      "9"
```

Also:

```
> sapply(df, class)
   ETDPAT04    ETDPAT06    ETDPAT08    ETDPAT12 
"character" "character" "character" "character"
```

I got df from:

```
t=data.table::fread("phs000086.v3.pht000279.v1.DS-T1D-IRB.txt", header=TRUE,na.strings = ".")
colnames(t) <- as.character(t[1,])
t <- t[2:nrow(t),]
df=select(t, ETDPAT04, ETDPAT06,ETDPAT08,ETDPAT12)
df <- sapply( df, as.numeric )
a=df[apply(df, 1, function(row) {any(row > 61)}),]
dim(a)
44  4
head(a)

     ETDPAT04 ETDPAT06 ETDPAT08 ETDPAT12
[1,]       NA       NA       NA       NA
[2,]       NA       NA       NA       NA
```

My original .txt data looks like this:

```
       phv00033517.v1.p1.c1 phv00033518.v1.p1.c1 phv00033519.v1.p1.c1
1:                PHASE                  AGE                ADULT
2:                    2                   17                    0
3:                    2                   29                    1
4:                    2                   35                    1
5:                    2                   14                    0
```

I wanted to remove the first row, and to make the 2nd row into header, so my column names become: PHASE, AGE ...

I also tried to do this in more basic way but still no solution:

```
library(dplyr)
d<- read.table("phs000086.v3.pht000279.v1.p1.c1.DCCT_ms2exprt.DS-T1D-   IRB.txt", header = FALSE)
write.table(d,"phen2", quote=F,sep = " ",row.names = F,col.names=F)
d1=read.table("phen2", header=TRUE)
d2=select(d1,AGE, FEMALE,HBAEL,ETDPAT00, ETDPAT02, ETDPAT04, ETDPAT06, ETDPAT08, ETDPAT10, ETDPAT12)
d2[d2=="."]<-NA

asNumeric <- function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x))
factorsNumeric <- function(d) modifyList(d, lapply(d[, sapply(d, is.factor)],   
                                               asNumeric))
f <- factorsNumeric(d2)
f[4:9] <- lapply(f[4:9], as.integer)

a=f[apply(t(f[,4:10]>61),1, any), ]
```

I 'm getting dataframe a with 800 or something rows all filled with NA. While I am trying to find any column where any values are >61.
The same if I look for any row where a value is > 61, getting 77 rows of all NAs

```
a=f[apply(t(f[,4:10]>61),2, any), ]

sapply(f, class)
      AGE    FEMALE     HBAEL  ETDPAT00  ETDPAT02  ETDPAT04  ETDPAT06     ETDPAT08 
"integer" "integer" "numeric" "integer" "integer" "integer" "integer"   "integer" 
 ETDPAT10  ETDPAT12 
"integer" "integer"
```

I am completely stuck here. Anyone can provide any help? Do I need to give more info about my data?

Comment: Looks like you found the issue yourself; the variable values are character, not numeric. Check how the data frame was created. Looks like there are "." characters, so you might need something like `na.strings = "."` _e.g._ if you used `data.table::fread`.

Comment: I tried to do: dat <- sapply( df, as.numeric ), but than after a=dat[apply(dat, 1, function(row) {any(row > 61)}),] I still got a with 44 NA rows in all 4 columns...

Comment: I selected those columns from a larger data frame: df=select(t, ETDPAT04, ETDPAT06,ETDPAT08,ETDPAT12), where t=data.table::fread("phs000086.v3.DS-T1D-IRB.txt", header=TRUE)

Comment: OK so try `t <- data.table::fread("phs000086.v3.DS-T1D-IRB.txt", header=TRUE, na.strings = ".")` if "." is the only character meaning NA.

Comment: didn't help please see the edits on the bottom of my post.

Comment: Why are you adding column names using the first row when the file has a header? I think the basic issue here is incorrect reading of the file, but it's hard to help without seeing the data in the file.

Comment: I agree, that is why I added how the original .txt data looks like, where I am removing the 1st row and turning the 2nd row into columns

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `DT` shown reproducibly in the Note at the end make the first row the header and convert the columns to numeric.  Then select the rows as indicated:

```
DT <- fread(paste(paste(do.call("paste", DT), collapse = "\n")), na.strings = ".")

DT[apply(DT > 61, 1, any), ]
## Empty data.table (0 rows) of 4 cols: ETDPAT04,ETDPAT06,ETDPAT08,ETDPAT12
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "
   ETDPAT04 ETDPAT06 ETDPAT08 ETDPAT12
        2        .        3        3
       12       12        .       14
        6        5        6        7
        1        1        1        1
        1        3        3        2
        3        3        2        4"

library(data.table)
DT <- fread(Lines, colClasses = "character", header = FALSE)
```

Comment: Hi, the issue is that I have to remove the first row in my data and make the 2nd row to be my header, that is why I do this in my code: colnames(t) <- as.character(t[1,])
t <- t[2:nrow(t),], please see addition in my post

Comment: OK. Have changed assumptions in answer.

Comment: It fails my my attempt to select those columns, please see: > DT <- fread("phs000086.v3.pht000279.v1.p1.c1.DCCT_ms2exprt.DS-T1D-IRB.txt", colClasses = "character", header = FALSE)
> hdr <- unlist(DT[1, ])
> DT <- DT[-1, ]
> DT=select(DT, ETDPAT04, ETDPAT06,ETDPAT08,ETDPAT12)
Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : object 'ETDPAT04' not found

Comment: DT looks like this:      V10    V11    V12    V13      V14    V15   V16   V17        V18  V19 V20
1: PPDUR PPDUR5 SMOKES RETPAT PUREPRIM QHBAEL HBAEL HBADF        MBP CHOL TRG
2:    52      0      1      2        0      3  9.63  1.01         68  184 111
3:   142      1      1      4        0      2  8.76  0.49 91.3333333  204  73
4:   175      1      3      4        0      2  7.93  -0.4 93.3333333  215 127

Comment: I have simplified the code but in any case both the new and old code work on the data in the Note at the end of the answer.  If what you have is different than what is in the question then you need to fix the question and provide the input in a reproducible manner.  You can use the Note to guide you in how to do that.  Do not provide this in a comment.

Comment: the last version of your edit gave me this:    V254 V255 V256 V257 V258 V259 V260 V261
1:   36   36   36   36   36   36   36    1
2:    4    4   12    4   12    4   36    2
3:   18   36   36   36   36   36   36    3
4:   20   36   36   36   36   36   36    4

Comment: the issue here is how to remove that first row and turn the 2nd row into headers and being able to get the proper column names in creating the new data frame with selection via: DT=select(DT, ETDPAT04, ETDPAT06,ETDPAT08,ETDPAT12). Neither of those two versions make a data frame with the above column names.On the bottom of my post I put before how exactly my original .txt file looks like.